# Null Pointer Exception when setting ImageView with Bitmap

Tags: android, surfaceview

This is the onCreate(...) method in my class:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.editor);
            setRequestedOrientation(1);

            v = new SView(this);
            v.setOnTouchListener(this);
            //v.setZOrderOnTop(true);
            //v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            setContentView(v);

            ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVEditor);
            bm = loadPhoto("photo", bm);
            if(bm != null)
            {
                    //This Section is giving me the error

                back.setImageBitmap(bm);

            }
        }
```

This is the error and when I double click it it brings me to the seperated portion above.  I do not know why though:

```
11-09 07:42:42.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32472): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 07:42:42.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32472):    at com.synlight_development.tattoo_it.Editor.onCreate(Editor.java:64)
11-09 07:42:42.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32472):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
11-09 07:42:42.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
11-09 07:42:42.624: E/AndroidRuntime(32472):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVEditor);
```

`R.id.IVEditor` has to be declared inside the layout you set with `setContentView`.

probably `R.id.IVEditor` is declared inside `R.layout.editor`. Swiching

```
 ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVEditor);
 bm = loadPhoto("photo", bm);
 if(bm != null) {
     back.setImageBitmap(bm);
 }
```

with

```
  v = new SView(this);
  v.setOnTouchListener(this);
  //v.setZOrderOnTop(true);
 //v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
  setContentView(v);
```

should make the trick. But all depends where `R.id.IVEditor` is declared;

Comment: I have gotten this to work, which is good.  The problem I am having now is that I had a Horizontal Scroll View in my layout, is there a way to show that on the screen now?

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your editor layout file contents over here. As that editor.xml layout file must have an ImageView as it's element with its id defined as `android:id = "@+id/IVEditor"`.
Then only you will get the exact ImageView object.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it it looks like you are replacing your `R.id.editor` layout with a new instance of `SView`. I haven't touched Android for a while so not sure what `SView` does. However i would start by thinking that it replaces your previous `setContentView(R.id.Editor)` with a custom view/layout/whater that doesn't include the layout element with the id `R.layout.IVEditor`.

So yeah, your trying to add an image to something that doesn't exist in your current layout. (`setContentView(v)` is removing the `R.id.editor` layout and putting in Sview() that doesn't contain `R.layout.IVEditor`.